# Finding Clock Cycle time without a specific instruction

Tags: mips, cycle, clock, latency, microprocessors

I understand that, given the latencies of say, IMem, Add , Mux , ALU ,  Regs, DMem and constrol , specific MIPS instruction such as add, and a specific datapath to work with, I am to find the critical path of the instruction on the datapath and add the latencies to come up with Clock Cycle Time. However, what if I am only given the latencies and the datapath, but no specific MIPS instruction? Do I just go with the longest single instruction and find its critical path? Or can I just add one instance of each individual latency to get a "general" clock cycle time?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: it would be a good idea if you could post the given problem, for more clarity on the issue

Comment: The way one determines the recommended clock speed is to look at the delays at the gate and transmission-line level of the circuitry inside the chip, allowing for manufacturing variation in those numbers, calculate the longest path between latches, and invert that time to get speed. But that's a hardware design question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the latency of the slowest single cycle instruction, since the clock must run slow enough to complete that instruction correctly.